Getting Access denied for administrator while trying to run a sudo command
I'm getting Access denied for the administrator while trying to run a sudo command, but the command is getting executed.

How to resolve this issue?

/etc/sudoers should never be directly edited.  Use the visudo command (sudo visudo) to edit it. Since the reboot command does not work, perhaps you are not in the sudo group.  Rather than try something which will interfere with the whole system to test access to sudo, try a simple command such as sudo ls

Does administrator have an aliased sudo? What does type -a sudo say?
